# Código equivalente do EASession no framework CoreFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estou com a seguinte dúvida. Hoje faço conexão com dispositivos externos utilizando `EAAccessoryManager` para identificação de dispositivos bluetooth pareados no iPad e o `EASession` para estabelecer uma sessão com o dispositivo. Eu gostaria de saber se existe algo similar ao `EASession` no `Core Foundation`, pois a implementação eu preciso realizar para um sistema legado em C.

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor o que quer dizer com sistema legado em C e o que precisa? Você não tem acesso nem a `ExternalAccessory` nem a `CoreBluetooth`?

Comment: Assim, na comunicação entre um dispositivo externo (pinpad) e minha aplicação em objective-c utilizo hoje as classes disponíveis para realizar esta tarefa (fiz isso para testes). Minha aplicação foi escrita a muito tempo em linguagem C para comunicação com estes dispositivos. Eu atualmente só queria saber se consigo manusear dispositivos como estou fazendo em objective-c utilizando linguagem C (talvez usando o framework Core Foundation) ou qualquer outra forma disponível pra isto, mas o código tem que estar em um fonte *.c. Espero ter conseguido explicar.